# How to set an imageview in the corner of card view

Tags: android, kotlin, floating-action-button

In my android app with kotin, in one of my interface, a recyclerview that contains a grid of cardview. In evrey items in the grid, i want to make an imageview in he corner of the cardview . 
The following code is belong to the item :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_small"
            app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            app:cardElevation="2dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutImageProduct"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/productImage"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/productName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/productDescription"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/productPrice"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_60"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/basket_ic"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want to put my imageview as the following image, what should i change in my code to get this result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpsZ1.png)

Comment: Why use floating button at all? Also try setting elevation to 0.

Comment: `Why use floating button at all?` this doesn't help with the question. `Also try setting elevation to 0` this doesn't help either

Comment: As for why FloatingButton, it's simply a subclass of `ImageButton` which provides additional functionality and looks which OP is looking for.

Comment: should i change it to ImageButton as you propose ?

Comment: if you want just a square icon,  use `ImageView`.

Comment: @Zun It was part of his question before edit, the "why use FB" part.

Comment: @Arun Jose how to change it to image view  and how to make it in this position like the picture

Comment: check the answer given below

Answer (score 0):

Below is solution

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/square"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**square.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

</shape>
```

As you see above code you just try to add android:background="@null" in your floating action button to remove background.

Answer (score 0):

```
try to add a constraint layout inside cardView.

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/card_view"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_small"
                app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutImageProduct"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/productImage"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/productName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/productDescription"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/productPrice"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_60"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_basket"
                android:tint="@color/black"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It's a very good response, but i want to put the image view in the corner of cardview., not all the imageview inside the cardview. Like the image above.

Comment: i change my code as yours, and i put the image above which contains the position of image view.Could you please help me

Comment: give some `marginTop` as some negative value. `marginTop = -30dp`